# Trying to set up Node.js application under subdomain on Windows Server

Tags: node.js, subdomain, windows-server

I'm attempting to set up my first Node.js application on Windows Server. The application runs fine with the command:

> node index.js

It'll run my application on localhost:8000. However, I want it to run on a subdomain on port 80, so I tried the following command:

> set PORT=80 && set HOST=api.mydomain.com && node index.js

And here is my index.js file, which handles setting the PORT and HOST in the app.listen command:

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
const config = require('./environment.json')[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'];

const app = express();
const port = +process.env.PORT || 8000;
const host = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';

// Skipping app.use commands...

app.get('/', root);

app.listen(port, host, 34, err => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  return console.log(`Server is listening on ${port}`);
});
```

Unfortunately, using a subdomain errors:

> events.js:187
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.mydomain.com
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26) Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1485:12)
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:17) {   errno: 'ENOTFOUND',   code: 'ENOTFOUND',   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
>   hostname: 'api.mydomain.com ' }

What is the proper way to configure the Node.js application to run under the subdomain? If I were using IIS it'd be as simple as adding additional Bindings, but now I'm in Node.js land instead so have no idea how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

[host](https://www.wistee.fr/configuration-nom-domaine/modifier-fichier-hosts.html)

No for your application to run locally with this domain name you must modify the host configurations to make api.mydomaine.com correspond to the ip address 127.0.0.1 on your machine

Comment: I added the subdomain to my HOSTS file and rebooted, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: use this code                                                                                          
    app.listen(port, err => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  return console.log(`Server is listening on ${port}`);
});

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just running it under IIS, using a reverse proxy. Then I could use IIS to set up the subdomain binding, much simpler...

https://dev.to/petereysermans/hosting-a-node-js-application-on-windows-with-iis-as-reverse-proxy-397b